# Como dejar de utilizar un 'case' en un switch Java

Tags: java, while, contador, switch

Estoy realizando un contador donde por consola se muestra "0-0-0", cuando lo inicializas, presionando '1' o '2' o '3' aumentará el contador según la posición en que esté, es decir si presiono '1' aumentará un valor y el contador mostrará "1-0-0", y así sucesivamente con los demás contadores eligiendo la opción que yo quiera aumentar.
El problema viene que yo lo tengo que aumentar hasta el valor '9'(nueve), una vez que algún contador llegue al valor nueve, se tiene que dejar de aumentar el contador y volverlo a reiniciar si es que el valor se aumenta a '10'(diez). Esto lo he realizado con un "if", donde le digo que si el primer contador es igual a nueve, que me inicialice devuelta a cero, mi duda es que si yo quiero dejarlo en el valor '9'(nueve) y quiero aumentar otro contador, se me vuelve a inicializar el contador que está con el valor '9', y no me permite salir nunca del ciclo while, no entiendo por que pasa esto, es decir por que se inicializa devuelta si ya no lo estoy utilizando más.

```
public class Ejercicio {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int contadorUno, contadorDos, contadorTres;
        char letraA, letraB, letraC, letraE;
        int aumentar;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        letraA = 'A';
        letraB = 'B';
        letraC = 'C';
        letraE = 'E';
        contadorUno = 0;
        contadorDos = 0;
        contadorTres = 0;

        do {
            System.out.println("Presionar 1-(Aumenta contador uno)||2-(Aumenta contador dos)||3-(Aumenta contador tres).");
            aumentar = sc.nextInt();
            switch (aumentar) {
                case 1:
                    contadorUno = contadorUno + 1;
                    System.out.println(contadorUno + "-" + contadorDos + "-" + contadorTres);
                    if(contadorUno == 9){
                        contadorUno = 0;
                    }
                    break;
                  
                case 2:
                    contadorDos = contadorDos + 1;
                    System.out.println(contadorUno + "-" + contadorDos + "-" + contadorTres);
                    if(contadorDos== 9){
                        contadorDos = 0;
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    contadorTres = contadorTres + 1;
                    System.out.println(contadorUno + "-" + contadorDos + "-" + contadorTres);
                    if(contadorTres == 9){
                        contadorTres = 0;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Error de ingreso,intente nuevamente.");
                    break;
            }
           
        } while (contadorUno != 9 || contadorDos != 9 || contadorTres != 9);

    }

}
```

Comment: Una posible solución que encontré es que en en la condición del if, lo iguale al valor 10, de esta forma se reiniciará a cero y también podré salir del bucle while, pero la idea es que no se muestre el 10.

Comment: Me parece que este ejercicio es para que aprendas a usar el operador módulo o residuo `%`, así no tendrás volver a poner el contador en 0, basta con que revises el residuo dividiendo el contador entre 10: `contador % 10`. También puedes usar el `++` para incrementar las variables en 1.

Answer (score 0):

Espero que esto te sirva.

Primero dentro de los case solo puse sumadores con sus condiciones, así solo hago las condiciones para cambiar los contadores mayores a 10 luego del switch.
Segundo fuera del switch, puse 3 condiciones para actualizar los contadores.

Primer if: si el contadorTres es 10 pasa a 0 y suma al contadorDos.
Segundo if: si el contadorDos es 10 y el contadorTres es diferente a 9 se le suma 1 al contadorTres y el contadorDos pasa a 0. Esto para que que el contadorDos solo pasa a 0 cuando el condatorTres aún puede aumentar.
Tercer if (siendo else if): contadorDos pasa a ser 9 cuando el contadorDos es 10 y el contadorTre ya es 9. Esto para no tener incrementos indeseados.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Ejercicio {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int contadorUno, contadorDos, contadorTres;
            char letraA, letraB, letraC, letraE;
            int aumentar;

            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            letraA = 'A';
            letraB = 'B';
            letraC = 'C';
            letraE = 'E';
            contadorUno = 0;
            contadorDos = 0;
            contadorTres = 0;
            do {
                System.out.println("Presionar 1-(Aumenta contador uno)||2-(Aumenta contador dos)||3-(Aumenta contador tres).");
                aumentar = sc.nextInt();
                switch (aumentar) {
                    case 1:
                        if (contadorUno < 9) contadorUno  += 1;
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        if (contadorUno < 9 && contadorDos <= 9) contadorDos += 1;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        contadorTres += 1;
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Error de ingreso,intente nuevamente.");
                        break;
                }
                if (contadorTres == 10){
                   contadorTres = 0;
                   contadorDos += 1;
                }
                if (contadorDos == 10 && contadorUno != 9){
                    contadorDos = 0;
                    contadorUno += 1;
                } else if (contadorDos == 10 && contadorUno == 9)
                    contadorDos = 9;
                System.out.println(contadorUno + "-" + contadorDos + "-" + contadorTres);
            } while (contadorUno != 9 || contadorDos != 9 || contadorTres != 9);
        }
    }
```

Por cierto si ponen letras como input se cae el programa, esto podría arreglarles al tratar String en ves de Integer, siendo `sc.next()` el método a usar y un tip, puedes colocar dentro del switch la lectura de input tal que `switch (sc.next())` y cambiar los case por "1", "2" y "3", así te ahorras el declarar una variable que solo le darás un uso único.

Ya para añadir un poco puedes colocar una bandera de error y al colocar cualquier elemento fuera de los casos imprima el error, pero no el estado actual de los contadores.

Comment: Interesante propuesta y solución!

Answer (score 0):

No se si no explicaste bien pero me parece que tu ejercicio debe ser asi:

1. Realizar un ejercicio de 3 contadores que vayan aumentado en 1 cuando se presione (1-2-3).
2. Si alguno de los contadores llega a 9 dejar de aumentar ese contador.
3. El ejercicio termina cuando los 3 contadores llegan a 9.

Esta última parte debería ser importante sino nunca saldría del bucle ( al menos no lo mencionas), Si estoy mal en la interpretación me comentas, en todo caso te dejo el código de acuerdo a lo que entendí.
**Estoy omitiendo las variables `char` que no se usan**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int contadorUno=0, contadorDos=0, contadorTres=0;        
        int aumentar;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);        
       
        do {
            System.out.println("Presionar 1-(Aumenta contador uno)||2-(Aumenta contador dos)||3-(Aumenta contador tres).");
            aumentar = sc.nextInt();
            switch (aumentar) {
                case 1:
                    if (contadorUno < 9) contadorUno++;
                    else break;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if (contadorDos < 9) contadorDos++;
                     else break;
                    break;
                case 3:if (contadorTres < 9) contadorTres++;
                 else break;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Error de ingreso,intente nuevamente.");
                    break;
            }
            System.out.println(contadorUno + "-" + contadorDos + "-" + contadorTres);
        } while (contadorUno != 9 || contadorDos != 9 || contadorTres != 9);
    }
```